# Dual passport different family name

Tags: dual-nationality, filipino-citizens, philippines

My son has 2 passsports with different family names. 1 passport is German with my family name (I am a single parent) and the 2nd one is Filipino where they used the family name of his father (my son was later acknowledged by his father and his birth cert was amended from my family name to his father's, the German Embassy in the Philippines didn't acknowledge this amendment and used my family name in my son's German passport instead). Since I was a young mom, I didn't argue with the German Embassy resulting to 2 passports now with different family names.

My concern now is, it is my first time travelling with my son from the Philippines to Germany. Knowing the Philippine immigration does a lot of profiling and offloading of Filipinos, does anyone know or has experience, if my son will be profiled for having 2 passports with different family names?

In our ticket I will put the name showing in the German passport since we will be entering Germany and I will use it all the way. I am just concerned we will be held at the Philippine immigration in Manila. What will be your advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "offloading of Filipinos"?

Comment: There is a big issue now in the Philippines, the immigration officers will profile and deny the Filipinos and will not let them out of the country. Foreigners are not affected on this, only Filipinos are being profiled and denied for boarding (offloaded).

Comment: The question is, can you *exit* the Philippines with the German passport‽ Presumably it doesn’t bear a visa of any kind, which would *definitely* lead to some questioning. You’d have to show the Philippines passport as proof that he was allowed to be in the Philippines in the first place, no? So, not much choice either way.

Comment: thanks for your comment- my main concern is if I will show the Filipino (Philippines) passport, it has a different family name versus the German passport. Anyways, thanks. I guess I'll have to figure this out on the day of our travel- if they will let us pass or not.

Comment: You should be able to change the name via a "Namenserklärung" which is (usually) a separate appointment at the embassy. But it will take a while.

Comment: Thank you @Marianne013 for the information, do you have any idea if the presence of the father is required when processing the "Namenserklärung".. though I will also try to check the German Embassy for more information on this, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would like to know if you were able to leave the Philippines concerning your issue. Same problem with me. In my Philippine passport I am using my mom’s family name. In my French passport I am using my dad’s family name.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are traveling together, both you and your son are German citizens, and dual citizenship is allowed by the Philippines, I would be very surprised if you have any problems leaving the Philippines.  Just present your son's German passport if asked.

Source: [Travel Clearance for Minors, Department of Social Welfare and Development](https://www.dswd.gov.ph/travel-clearance-for-minors/):

> WHO ARE EXEMPTED TO SECURE TRAVEL CLEARANCE?
>
> A minor accompanied by the following:
>
> Either or both of the minor’s parents, if legitimate minor;
>
> The minor’s biological mother, if illegitimate minor; [...]
>
> A minor who is an immigrant or a permanent resident abroad, with
> foreign passport

Comment: yes, but my concern is it has different family names- the German passport and the Filipino (Philippines) passport, my son might get held and they might not let him pass since his Filipino passport doesn't have a Schengen Visa.. while the German passport might get rejected  by the officer since it is a mismatch with the Filipino (Philippines) passport

Comment: @user141271 I doubt this will be an issue since everything else including biodata still matches, but you can bring along his birth certificate, which lists both names.

Comment: It gets worse. You may have difficulties with presenting the German passport to the BI officer since you son probably does not have an Philippines visa in it and you do not have an ECC for your son associated with this passport.  This is a known issue.

Comment: @fpmurphy "ECC"?

Comment: ECC - Exit Clearance Certificate.